# ORM Design using Pyramid and SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I need some help to create my model for the ORM.

I've been trying to design a web application using Pyramid and SQLAlchemy as a personal learning experience as well as being a smaller component for a web application I wish to develop for the company I work for.

A little background on what this application will be about(*construction field of work*).

It will be used as a bid schedule that our estimators will be able to update; so that the secretaries in our front office will be able to see who is working on what job and what contractors the job is getting estimated for.

I've got 3 models designed and they look like this:

```
class JobListing(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'joblist'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    jobname = Column(String(80), unique=True)
    biddate = Column(DateTime)

    def __init__(self, jobname, biddate):
        self.jobname = jobname
        self.biddate = biddate

class Contractors(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'contractors'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(80), unique=True)
    address = Column(String(255))
    phone = Column(String(11))
    fax = Column(String(11))

    def __init__(self, name, address, phone, fax):
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
        self.phone = phone
        self.fax = fax

class BiddingList(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'biddinglist'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    job_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("joblist.id"))
    job = relationship("JobListing", backref=backref("joblist", order_by=id))
    contractor_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("contractors.id"))
    contractors = relationship("Contractors", backref=backref("contractors", order_by=id))
```

joblisting contains the actual job information; job name and bid date are all that is needed.

Contractors contains the information that is specific to actual contractor we will be bidding, just the standard information such as phone fax etc etc.

Biddinglist will contain the information I'm not sure on how I should organize. I believe this is the correct way but it should just connect the contractors to the job ids.

The contractor can only be listed once per job but the job can have many contractors.

My question is, Am I approaching this the right way with this design or am I completely out in left field? I just want to go about this the right way from the start so I have a solid foundation to work on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to store any additional info in the `BiddingList` object, just `job_id` and `contractor_id` - this pattern is called a [many-to-many relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/tutorial.html#building-a-many-to-many-relationship), and SQLAlchemy docs have an example of how to set it up. Basically, you don't need an intermediate ORM class in this case (although you need a table), and after you've set everything up, the usage will look like

```
job = JobListing(jobname="Test Job")
job.contractors.append(joe)
job.contractors.append(bob)
print bob.jobs
> [<JobListing "Test Job">]
bob.jobs.append(another_job)
print bob.jobs
> [<JobListing "Test Job">, <JobListing "Another Job">]
```

-- everything is nice and transparent.

If you want to store some additional info on the many-to-many relation (for example, a contractor can have a different `role` in each `JobListing`) - this is a different pattern called [Association Object](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/relationships.html#association-pattern).

If you want to restrict the relationship so every contractor can be added just once, I'd look at specifying a [unique constraint](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/schema.html?highlight=constraint#sqlalchemy.schema.UniqueConstraint)

Now you know all the magic words to make it work :)

One additional note - despite some examples on the net, you don't need to add a constructor for each ORM class - SQLAlchemy provides a default `__init__` method which accepts parameters which match the names of the columns:

```
class JobListing(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'joblist'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    jobname = Column(String(80), unique=True)
    biddate = Column(DateTime)

obj = JobListing(jobname="Test Job", biddate=datetime.now())
```

Comment: Thanks for the great information this was exactly what i was looking for!